# Hangman game -error in the while loop

Tags: python

I hve created a hangman game on python but it doesn't seem to be working...
here's code:

```
guessed = ''

lives = 7

while lives > 0:

    missed = 0
    print()
    for letter in generated_word:
        if letter in guessed:
            pritn (letter,end=' ')
        else:
            print ('_',end=' ')
            missed = missed + 1
    if missed == 0:
        print ('You win!')  
        quit()
        break
    guess=input("please guess a letter:")


    guessed = guessed + guess
    if guess not in generated_word:

        print ('\n That letter is not in this word, your lives have been decreased by 1.')
        print ('Please try another letter.')
        lives = lives - 1 
        missed = missed + 1

        print('your new lives value is')

        print(lives)

        if lives < 7:
            print('''   _______
   |    |   ''')
            if lives < 6:
                print('   |    O    ') 
            if lives < 5:            
                print('   |    |    ')
            if lives < 4:
                print('   |  \- -/  ')
            if lives < 3: 
                print('   |    |    ')
            if lives < 2:
                print('   |   / \\  ')
            if lives < 1:
                print('   |  /   \\ ')
            if lives == 0:
             print('___|___      ')
             print('GAME OVER! You have run out of lives and lost the game')
             print('The random word was...')
             print(generated_word)
             quit()
```

any help please? it says that print is not defined?
I am new and have lots of mistakes, and I will be grateful if anyone could correct this code.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Also, please post the complete text of the error (a stack trace if you have one).

Comment: Print is defined, pritn is not.

Comment: Seems like you have declared any value to generated_word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a spelling mistake in one of your print statements:

```
missed = 0
print()
for letter in generated_word:
    if letter in guessed:
```

Here is the spelling error

```
        print (letter,end=' ')
```

And this is the rest of your code

```
    else:
        print ('_',end=' ')
        missed = missed + 1
if missed == 0:
    print ('You win!')  
    quit()
    break
guess=input("please guess a letter:")
```

This should fix the section.

Comment: Can you exactly specify where the spelling mistake is?

Comment: Sorry, should've specified that :)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is another homework assignment as similar "hangman" questions has been asked like 4/5 times this past 2 weeks.You have a few mistakes:

1)You did not assign any value to `generated_word` and hence error will occur when you try to run the for-loop. You should make a list of random words then access them randomly and assign it to `generated_words`.

2)The 2nd print statement inside your `while` loop is spelled wrong.